# Is it possible to reuse a proxy, after a database raise error, in GWT RF?

Tags: hibernate, gwt, oracle11g, requestfactory

I've found a lot of dead links that say "You can't reuse an EntityProxy, after a Constraint validation happening in the database".

There are some constraints that I can't really verify them in the client side, so I would like them to be retrieved from the database, and then reuse my EntityProxy to correct the errors.

For example, I have an entity, let's call it **`ServiceEntity`** that has on the database an simple Index like this(**`lower(name)`**).

At the point of **`saving/updating a Service`**, if the **`database raises that index constraint violation`**, I'd like to **`reuse my proxy`** and **`reedit it`**(to correct the wrong fields and save it again)

Even if the exception caught it's a "ConstrainValidatonException", the failed request goes on the onFailure() method, not on the onConstraint method.

I've tried one proposed solution(**deep cloning**, of the entity proxy) and it really **works**. But it really works only for a **persist/save action**. For a **merge** action, the cloning it's useless. The old objects that are already in the database are taken by the hibernate as new objects, and it tries to persist them in the database(and the index or other constraints are raised)

***Updates:
So it seems I haven't made myself clear.***

I have in the database on a table called "`SERVICE`" an the following index on the "`NAME`" column **`(lower(name))`**. So in the "SERVICE" table can't be 2 records that have the same lower(name).

Let's say the "`SERVICE`" table contains a record with the name "`JOB`".

In GWT i try to persist a new ServiceProxy, into that table, and I give it's name "`jOB`". That will raise an error in the database, an Constraint Violation Error. I can't verify this before firing the request to the server, so the database should return the error, and I should reedit the proxy, and correct it's name(to be a valid one).

The stack will look as follows:

```
[INFO] 2014-01-29 13:12:18,562 [qtp25907110-42] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00001: unique constraint (SERVICE_INDEX1) violated
[INFO]
[INFO] 2014-01-29 13:12:18,566 [qtp25907110-42] ERROR xxx.CustomRequestFactoryServlet$LoquaciousExceptionHandler - Server error
[INFO] org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [SERVICE_INDEX1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintVi
olationException: could not execute statement
[INFO]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:138)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:680)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:562)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
```

I display a custom error message to the client like this "There is already a service with the given name. Please choose another name", and then i'd like to reedit the proxy, change the name, and fire again the proxy to the server.

This are the steps

Comment: Validation is handled before service calls go off (but after setters are called) in RF's server lifecycle, its meant to be a different sort of concern. This must be, because one or more *other* calls may have already completed, or part of the *current* call may have already completed. What is the case where the database is raising an error?

Comment: The life cycle of your Proxy ends the moment you call fire. So if you trying to do a traitement of your Proxy in the failure methode, you're gonna get an "A request is already in progress" error. Can you post the StackeTrace ?

Comment: I've updated my post, and added the requested stacktrace. And yeah I'm getting an "A request is already in progress" error, but in my case i'd like it to reuse my context, because it's a ConstraintViolationException, and it shouldnt go on the onFailure() method from the Receiver, it should go on the onConstraintViolation() method from the Receiver class. It violates a Constraint Exception, not a fatal exception.